# How would I create and render, but not save, an entire menu tree programmatically?

Tags: navigation, 9

I'm trying to pull a number of links from several services, and combine them into a renderable menu tree:

Source one: pull links A, B and C

Source two: pull links D and E

Source three: pull links F, G, and H

Desired end result: a menu tree object that I can render using core and contrib menu theming functions, structured like:

- Parent 1

  - Link A
  - Link B
  - Link C
- Parent 2

  - Link D
  - Link E
- Parent 3

  - Link F
  - Link G
  - Link H

It seems like this is simple enough to do with a menu that's been saved to the database, but as the contents of the links from each of these sources may change at any time, I'm looking to build the menu on the fly. I can create menu items out of the data, but I'm having trouble creating and populating a tree with them. All the documentation and posts I've been able to find seem to assume you're loading a tree from a pre-existing menu. I think what I need to do is create a new, empty tree, and add the links to it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The Drupal way to do this would be to build the object and cache it, but add cache tags to it. Then when the data changes that would affect the rendering of the item (in your case, one of the items on the tree), you would invalidate the cache tags, which would force your menu to be rebuilt the next time it was requested. This way you aren't building it every time it's requested, but rather only when a rebuild is required.

Comment: True, caching would be good -- but I think that still leaves the problem of actually creating and populating the menu tree in the first place, yes? I suppose one way to do it would be to create an empty menu and manipulate its tree, but I'd rather not have a menu sitting there in the admin interface when I don't actually want people doing anything with it.

Comment: This is not correct, you only save menu link content to the database. In general menu links are plugins which can be more dynamic than database content and, to connect it with @Jaypan comment, MenuLinkInterface implements CacheableDependencyInterface to make dynamic menu links cacheable.